# Magento 2.0 REST/SOAP API - how to retrieve Special Price

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, soap, special-price

I need to be able to **retrieve the Special Price of a product**.

I can successfully retrieve products singly or as a list, but can only see a `price` property on the product object. I also cannot see anything like Special Price in the `customAttributes` or `extensionAttributes`.

In **Magento 1.x APIs**, Special Price was a fixed property of a product. **Has something changed in Magento 2**?

I am working with the SOAP API, using the `catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList` and `catalogProductRepositoryV1Get` methods of the `catalogProductRepositoryV1` service, but if you can explain wrt to REST API, I can translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was this (I don't know if this is the only solution):

The Magento provider I was working with had to make an update to the products API such that the special price was exposed as a "custom attribute". Then the special price could be retrieved and submitted as an attribute.

Example snippet of JSON:
{ sku :567687978083535, custom_attributes : { special_price:333 } }

I don't know what changes were made on the Magento side to accomplish this, sorry.